# SQL function not working through Wordpress' $wpdb

Tags: sql, wordpress

So, I'm developing a Wordpress theme about poetry.

There's an archive page for the actual poets; through AJAX and a custom SQL query I have managed to load poets whose names start with a specific letter of the alphabet, but here's the problem: poets must be sorted by surname, not by name.

I have decided to use a custom **SPLIT_STR** SQL function found on the web that looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
END;
```

and I have used this SPLIT_STR function inside of my query to select the surname of the poet and determine its first letter. Here's the query:

```
$postids = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT ID
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE SUBSTR( SPLIT_STR($wpdb->posts.post_title, ' ', 2), 1, 1) = %s
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_title", $letter
));
```

That said, here's the problem:
**even if this query works just fine on local, I can't get it to work on the running website.**

*Things you need to know*:

1. The same query works when inserted into the query form of phpMyAdmin.
2. Running `$wpdb->query("SELECT SPLIT_STR('some thing', ' ', 2)");` actually works correctly and returns "thing".

I am very confused about this but I hope I've been able to at least describe the problem successfully. Does any of you guys understand what's going on here?

Comment: Have you add global $wpdb; above your query?

Comment: Yup, I have. As I was saying, everything works correctly on localhost

Comment: Since I couldn't solve this problem I have chosen to change strategy and add a "letter" custom field for my post type. I think this was the best alternative performance-wise.
I'll just leave the question here though, since I'm still curious about the answer